# i want to download Pixelmon Reforged but I only have a Microsoft account not a Mojang so I cant sign up in technic. Can anyone help me?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-mods, minecraft-technic-pack, minecraft-pixelmon

On Technic Launcher, you have to sign into your Mojang account to get into it so if people only have a Microsoft account then they cant sign in. I tried to create a Mojang  account but it takes me straight to the sign in not sign up even when it says create account, when you click on it, it takes you to sign in so i need a way to sign up.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to buy the game again as Microsoft Store/Xbox and Java/Mojang accounts are different things.

This is the same deal as having to buy the game again when you play on both iOS and Android.